# Using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following table:

```
Email | value | group
 a    |   1   |   x
 a    |   2   |   y
 a    |   3   |   y
 b    |   3   |   z
```

I previously wrote code to pull the sum of values by distinct email in each group, to get this:

```
Email | value | group
 a    |   1   |   x
 a    |   5   |   y
 b    |   3   |   z
```

The code looked like this:

```
 SELECT distinct email,
        group,
        sum (value)
  from t
 group by email, group
```

Now, I want to sum by groups of groups using CASE, to get this output:

```
 Email | value | super_group
 a     |   6    |   x_y
 b     |   3    |   z
```

But this code *doesn't* work:

```
 SELECT distinct email,
        CASE when group in (x,y) 
             then 'x_y'
             else 'z' 
        end as super_group,
        sum (value)
   from t
  group by email, super_group
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using Teradata

Comment: thanks. any suggestions?

Comment: The `distinct` in `SELECT distinct email, group` makes no sense since you are grouping by `email, group` which guarantees their combination is unique

Comment: "doesn't work" should be accompanied by additional information, presumably by an error message

Comment: `x` and `y` are strings, not columns.  
Technically  it should be `('x','y')` and not `(x,y)` (but the logic is wrong)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ARRAY_AGG**

Also, if you are using a GROUP BY you don't need the DISTINCT. Try this way:

First you will have to define an ARRAY Type like this:

```
-- note the varchar with size 20 is a sample you should pick yours
-- and the size of the array is also an example
CREATE TYPE group_array AS VARCHAR(20) ARRAY[100];
```

Then you can make your query return the array type with the group value aggregated.

```
SELECT email,
       sum (value) as value,
       ARRAY_AGG(group, NEW group_array()) as super_group
 FROM t
GROUP BY email
```

That should give you as result:

```
 email   | value  | super_group
   a     |   6    |   ( x, y )
   b     |   3    |   ( z )
```

Reference to [ARRAY_AGG](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/ARRAY_Functions.081.024.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a newer version of Teradata you can use XMLAGG() to do this:

```
SELECT 
    email,
    sum(value),
    trim(trailing '_' FROM (XMLAGG(group || '_' ORDER BY group) (VARCHAR(50))))
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
```